# Screen tearing on Nvidia GeForce 840M

Tags: 16.04, screen, asus, nvidia-geforce

My laptop is an ASUS A455LN, and got troubled when running Ubuntu.

As the title implies, the screen having some slight screen tearing issue. This actually it isn't a problem, but it comes to be a problem when using (especially when running 3D programs e.g games from Steam). It's inconvinent when playing games with screen tearing. Though I set the vsync on in-game, it won't work properly (FPS capped but screen still tearing).

I remembered correctly the screen didn't tear when using Intel graphics, but it makes Nvidia graphics left unused. Any way to remove screen tearing on Nvidia?

What did I do previously:

- Purged all generic `nvidia*` drivers downloaded from Ubuntu repository
- Installed `nvidia-375` from `graphics-drivers` PPA

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command `nvidia-settings` (This will only work if you are using Nvidia proprietary driver). A GUI will pop-up. Click `X Server Display Configuration`. Once you select it, click `Save to X Configuration File`

Open your terminal and run this as root:
`nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Add `{ ForceCompositionPipeline = On }` to the `"Screen"` Section in the `"metamodes"` Option:

```
Option         "metamodes" "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +2560+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }, DP-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

I have two monitors, both connected to Display Port (DP). So I added it to `DP-0` and `DP-2`. Adjust appropriately based on your setup.